# Laravel Model Path Printed

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am not sure why, but the path to the model is always printed out once when I am printing out data using eloquent when I am referencing to another model.

I am trying out a tutorial from this link: http://scotch.io/tutorials/php/a-guide-to-using-eloquent-orm-in-laravel

below is the code I am running.

```
$bearLawly = Bear::where('name', '=', 'Lawly')->first();
echo $bearLawly->name;
echo '<br/>';

foreach($bearLawly->trees as $tree){
    echo $tree->type;
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

The output that I am getting is below.

```
Lawly
// app/models/Tree.php Redwood
Oak
```

Is there anyone who knows how to resolve the issue of model name being printed out whenever I am referencing to another model?

The model name only gets printed out the first time I am using the data. It happens for all additional models I am referencing from.

It happens when I am using the magic method to pull the referenced model. If I am calling directly from the model, the printing of model path does not happen.

Shown in the output above, calling bear info is okay but when I pull the trees in which is from another model using eloquent, the model path gets printed out.

Comment: Do you have perhaps a "type" function in your model too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look on the tutorial. Did you notice, that there are comments before the actual php tag?
This could be the reason?

```
// app/models/Tree.php
<?php

class Tree extends Eloquent {
...
```

Comment: Yes! Spot on. Totally missed that out. Removed the comment lines before the PHP open tag which resolved the issue. Thank you!